# How do you define multiple yield types in a TypeScript iterable?

Tags: typescript, iterator

I have an iterable and array destructuring that works but doesn't type check correctly. I'm pretty new to TypeScript so I'm guessing that I'm doing something wrong. I'm using TypeScript 3.8.2.

This example works because no type checking occurs, but uncommenting the last line causes the error below this code example to show up.

```
function MakeIterable<T> (a: T, b: number, c: boolean) {
    const result = [ a, b, c ]

    function* gen(): Generator<T | number | boolean, void, void> {
        let v
        while (v = result.shift()) {
            yield v
        }
    }

    return gen()
}

const [a, b, c] = MakeIterable(new Date(), 5, true)
console.log(a, b, c)
// a.setDate(0)
```

Error output after uncommenting `a.setDate(0)`:

```
Error:(16, 7) TS2339: Property 'setDate' does not exist on type 'number | boolean | Date'.
  Property 'setDate' does not exist on type 'number'.
```

Also, modifying the Generator definition to limit it to one returned type fixes it, but the second and third items off the iterator will not be the type that TypeScript thinks it is. TypeScript thinks all items must be Date objects in this case.

Modified example line:

```
function* gen(): Generator<T, void, void> {
```

**Question:** What is the correct way to define the different value types that come back from the iterator? Ideally the types in order (in this case `T, number, boolean`) would be nice.

Comment: This is limitation of yield type definition. Looks like currently there's no way to define a sequence of different types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type definition for `Generator` or `Iterator` does not support ordered sequence of return types - [stricter generators](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-6.html). But also, logically, ordered sequence of return types would be broken more often then not.

It would work only in simplest cases, when `next()` is called within the same scope/file, sequentially, until the sequence ends. Given example is too trivial, so that generator can be omitted completely.

For example, if `next()` is called via event handler, or generator is shared between multiple components, specifying order of types would potentially lead to runtime errors. Therefore, union type `T | number | boolean` is appropriate output for generator.

Correct approach, to cover all use-cases, is to use type guards on returned values.

```js
if (a instanceof Date) {
    a.setDate(0);
}
```

Comment: That is a good explanation of why what I'm trying to do doesn't work. Thank you for taking the time to answer it.